# With python, how do I change the values of list using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

I have array like:

```
foo foot oot
foo foot oot
bar bart art
bar bart art
```

I have dict

```
{ foo : 1, bar :2, foot:34, bart:54, oot:123}
```

Looking to map or apply on set for this output:

```
1 34 123
1 34 123
2 54 NaN
2 54 NaN
```

Notice: one value is missing. I was thinking of slicing each column,
then doing a list comprehesion, But this feels wrong.

Comment: That array doesn't look like any Python structure *I've* ever seen...

Comment: Its an array, numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
>>> lis = [['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
['bar', 'bart', 'art'],
['bar', 'bart', 'art']]
>>> dic = { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' :2, 'foot':34, 'bart':54, 'oot':123}
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> [[dic.get(y,nan) for y in x] for x in lis]
[[1, 34, 123], [1, 34, 123], [2, 54, nan], [2, 54, nan]]
```

`dict.get(key, default_value)` : returns the value related to key if the `key` is found else returns the `default_value`.

We can't use `NaN` directly in python, that's why used `float('nan')`.

Comment: Is there a faster, NumPy-specific way to implement this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not sure about `numpy`, I thought the question was related to normal 2D-list.

Comment: The "array" in the question made me probe further.

Comment: Can you explain: .get(y,nan) and float('nan'), see what they do, but would like to know what they do.

Comment: Unless there is a better answer, I can .tolist() to convert numpy array to python list...

Comment: @Merlin `dic.get(y, nan)` is equivalent to `dic[y]` (i.e, it gets the value from the dict). But if the key is not found, instead of raising a KeyError, it puts in `nan`.

Comment: @Merlin `.tolist()` works fine, I am sure there there would be way to this in `numpy` as well.

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays, the following numpy only code will probably perform better:

```
arr = np.array([['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
                ['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
                ['bar', 'bart', 'art'],
                ['bar', 'bart', 'art']])

dict_ = {'foo' : 1, 'bar' : 2, 'foot' : 34, 'bart' : 54, 'oot' : 123}

arr_flat = arr.ravel()

keys = np.array(dict_.keys())
vals = np.array(dict_.values())
sort_idx = np.argsort(keys)
keys = keys[sort_idx]
vals = vals[sort_idx]
vals = np.concatenate((vals, [np.nan]))

unique, indices = np.unique(arr_flat, return_inverse=True)
locs = np.searchsorted(keys, unique, side='left')
no_match = unique != keys[locs]
locs[no_match] = len(keys)

new_arr = np.take(vals, np.take(locs, indices)).reshape(arr.shape)
# Same as new_arr = vals[locs[indices]].reshape(arr.shape)

>>> arr
array([['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
       ['foo', 'foot', 'oot'],
       ['bar', 'bart', 'art'],
       ['bar', 'bart', 'art']], 
      dtype='|S4')
>>> new_arr
array([[   1.,   34.,  123.],
       [   1.,   34.,  123.],
       [   2.,   54.,   nan],
       [   2.,   54.,   nan]])
```